# How to start a data frame with a row name of 1 in r

Tags: r, html-table

How do I start this table with a row name of 1? Maryland should be row1,  Wisconsin should be row2, etc.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdM9Y.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the rownames.

```
row.names(df) <- NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been working on my homework for hours! It works now!